# IDebugSymbols doesn't find symbols in symbol server

Tags: windows, debug-symbols, dbghelp

I am writing a small application that prints out the call stack of a given crash dump. The code is more or less base on this tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2008/05/27/opening-a-crash-dump-file-automating-crash-dump-analysis-part-1.aspx?Redirected=true

The code works fine when the debug symbol is alongside the crash dump. However my application can't find the debug symbol when it lives in a symbol server. My symbol server is specified in `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`. I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` and the symbol server because when I open the crash dump in Visual Studio and WinDbg, they are able to find the symbol in the symbol server.

I added the `SYMOPT_DEBUG` option to my instance of `IDebugSymbols` and I get the following output:

`DBGHELP: _NT_SYMBOL_PATH`:

```
srv*c:\localsymbols*my_symbol_server*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

`DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path`:

```
.;srv*c:\localsymbols*my_symbol_server*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

I guess that means that my instance of IDebugSymbols knows about the symbol server.

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get windows debugging tools ( from Windows Kits now ) and use components
dbgeng.dll, dbghelp.dll and symsrv.dll from it. OS has standard version of these dll in System32 and unfortunately they has restricted functions. For example they dont support symbol servers on windows 7.

may be you find our projects usefull:

[kdlibcpp](http://kdlibcpp.codeplex.com)
[pykd - python wrapper for kdlibcpp](http://pykd.codeplex.com)

For example this code print out current stack:

```
StackPtr  stk = getStack();
for ( int i = 0; i < stk->getFrameCount(); ++i )
    dprintln( findSymbol( stk->getFrame(i)->getIP() ) )
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for your help. I'll check out pykd. It looks like it could be very useful.